# How to join the table

Tags: sql-server

Here i have 2 tables and i need to join the table as i am a beginner please help me to solve

```
Table1                   Table2
ins1 ins2 ins3           Insc0
 1     2    0              1
 3     4    0              2
 5     6    0              3
                           4
                           5
```

is this below code right?

```
select t2.insco from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.ins1=t2.insco
union
select t2.insco from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.ins2=t2.insco
union
select t2.insco from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.ins3=t2.insco
```

Comment: No, this isn't the right way. The main reason is because your data isn't normalised; and you should really be fixing that design. Is that something you can do now, before it's too late? If not, you'll need to normalise your data in the query to get the "best" way. A bunch of `UNION` queries is going to be one of the least performant ways.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu.
Sorry as i am a Beginner. How to normalize my data?
yeah i got it.. i will try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I mentioned, you need to normalise your data. This is every much overly simplified, due to the simplicity of your data, however, should get you on the right path:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable1 (RowID int--,
                             --Other columns, but no ins1, 2, etc columns
                             );
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable1 (RowID--,
                            --Other columns
                           )
VALUES(1),(2),(3);--Obviouslu, again you would have other columns, but not an ins columns

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable2 (Insc0 int);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable2 (Insc0)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

CREATE TABLE dbo.LinkTable (RowID int,
                            Ins int);
INSERT INTO dbo.LinkTable (RowID,
                           Ins)
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),
      (2,3),(2,4),
      (3,5),(3,6);

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable1 YT1
     JOIN dbo.LinkTable LT ON YT1.RowID = LT.RowID
     JOIN dbo.YourTable2 YT2 ON LT.Ins = YT2.Insc0;

GO

--Clean up

DROP TABLE dbo.LinkTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable2;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable1;
```

Comment: You're welcome @Vigneshs, please do consider accepting the answer as the solution and/or upvoting if it solved the problem, so that future readers know that the answer was helpful, should they have the same/similar question. Thanks.

Comment: Would be great to here from the downvoter here. How can this be improved?